# Android:Attach file with email from device memory

Tags: android, email

In my application, I want to be able to send email.  I am able to send email with text.  However, I want to add attach file or photo from device memory in email. Does anybody have any ideas on how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the demo of doing "Email with file attachment".

**Note**: Below code is taking file stored inside your sd-card and add as an attachment to the email.

```
try 
   {        
       String fileName = URLEncoder.encode(yourfilename, "UTF-8");
       String PATH =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+fileName.trim().toString();

       Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+PATH);
       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       i.setType("text/plain");
       i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
       i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"android - email with attachment");
       i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");
       i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
       context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select application"));
   } 
   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
   {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: It is not working when i am sending the email again with same subject