# Notify application if email has been sent in Android

Tags: android, email

I am sending an email with attachment using the code provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4918531/1594522

The sending is working fine. Now, I want to notify my application once the sending of email finished. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Call startActivityForResult instead of startActivity, then you can implement your own onActivityResult method that will get called when the email activity is complete.

Comment: I'm not sure onActivityResult is called when email is **sent**

Comment: I forgot to mention that i have already tried this before I posted my question, and onActivityResult is not being called. :(