# Export or Send Email from Android WebView Application

Tags: android, webview

I have built a WebView application that stores some information in DOM storage (localstorage).  As part of the application, I would like to export that data either to a .csv file or to an email (attached as .csv, etc).

I'm able to get the data in a .csv format, but I'm not sure how to export or send an email with the data.

Upon clicking the "Export" button, I have tried the following:

```
var currentData = getHistorySummary("myObject");
var dataArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < currentData.length; i++) {
dataArray.push(JSON.parse(currentData[i]));
}
dataArray.sortBy('id');
var csv = convertJSONtoCSV(dataArray);

var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
csvContent += csv;
var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
window.open(encodedUri);
```

However nothing happens at this point, and I receive the following warning:

Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 27146

Is there a better way to "export" this information, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following (the .csv content gets sent in the body of the email):

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("data:text/csv")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:someone@example.com"));
                i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, URLDecoder.decode(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

It's not ideal, but for the project I'm working on, it will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by giving your file name and file path-

```
 try 
   {        
       String fileName = URLEncoder.encode(yourfilename, "UTF-8");
       String PATH =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+fileName.trim().toString();

       Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+PATH);
       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       i.setType("text/plain");
       i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
       i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"android - email with attachment");
       i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");
       i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
       i.setType("text/csv");
       context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select application"));
   } 
   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
   {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

source link[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918235/androidattach-file-with-email-from-device-memory)

Comment: I don't actually have a filename or path, as the .csv content is generated from DOM localstorage (into a URI).  Is there a way to generate a file from the URI itself and then attach that perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebView#addJascriptInterface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)) and publish a method that sends the email, probably also passing the data in the localstorage too.